# NAT loopback on my router

Tags: router, port-forwarding, iptables, nat, loopback

Tried all for a day still can't get it done.

I am trying to configure 'NAT loopback' on my router.

- **Router LAN IP**: `192.168.1.254` (br0)
- **Router WAN IP**: `192.168.10.129`
- **Web-server LAN IP**: `192.168.1.1`

I am trying to access the web-server running on `192.168.1.1` from `192.168.1.2`.

If this done. i would try to access the same from **WAN to LAN** i.e. i will connect another router in my office network and from the client of 2nd router i would like to access the same web-server page.

**Default iptables list before configuring:**

```
# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             224.0.0.0/24

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere
```

I tried below iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.10.129/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.254
```

Answer (score 1):

### [SOLVED]

> Tested and okey..!

### Dynamic values:

> **WAN Interface:** vlan10
>   **LAN Interface:** br0
>
> **LAN Web server IP:** 192.168.1.1
>   **LAN Web server Port**: 8080
>
> **Router WAN IP:** 192.168.10.129
>   **Router LAN IP:** 192.168.1.254

### 1. [port-forwarding](/questions/tagged/port-forwarding) rules

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i vlan10 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i vlan10 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1
```

### 2. [nat-loopback](/questions/tagged/nat-loopback) rules

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.10.129/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.254
```

*NOTE: Remember to disable the other network LAN interface while testing..*